# panda convert column to list and add new column

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

New to Python. I am trying to convert column C to list and add it as extra column D in df.
I tried list() it work for individual raw. But it doesn't work for whole column C in df.
I need hint/help to move forward.

Input

```
A   B   C 
----------------
1  21  12457643  
2  32  34576543  
3  41  23456789
```

Output

```
A   B   C              D
------------------------------------
1  21  12457643   [1,2,4,5,7,6,4,3]  
2  32  34576543   [3,4,5,7,6,5,4,3]  
3  41  23456789   [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: Please fix your question formatting. What exactly are the contents of 'Blockquote' supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

In general,  storing lists in pandas columns is not a very good idea. But if you insist, convert the numbers to strings and then to lists of characters:

```
df['D'] = df['C'].astype(str).apply(list)
#0    [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 4, 3]
#1    [3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
#2    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The result is a list of characters. If you want a list of single-digit numbers, you need to apply a custom function via `lambda`:

```
df['D'] = df['C'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: list(map(int, x)))
#0    [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 4, 3]
#1    [3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
#2    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `findall`

```
df.C.astype(str).str.findall(r'(.)')
0    [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 4, 3]
1    [3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
2    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Name: C, dtype: object
```